# Is there a name for this topology?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

First off, I want to  point out a popular topology for the real line. We know it commonly as the Michael line. It is given by

$\mathfrak{T}_M =\{U \cup I: U$ is open under usual topology, $I \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \}$.

But is there a name for the topology given by

$\mathfrak{T} =\{U \cup Q: U$ is open under usual topology, $Q \subset  \mathbb{Q} \}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined in *Counterexamples in Topology* as space #70, [Discrete rational extension of $\mathbb R$](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000062).

Comment: Interestingly we don't have "Michael Line" as an alias of [S63](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000063); this should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the feedback!